# Вызов qml из .so (.dll) Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, dll, qml

1. Создал `.so` (`.dll`) на *Qt*, используя *QLibrary*
2. Подключил его к основному приложению используя *QPluginLoader*

Все функции, описанные в `.so` (`.dll`) вызываются в основной программе правильно.

Какими средствами можно ретранслировать (вызвать/открыть) *qml*-окно/страницу из `.dll` в окне основной программы, также написанной на *qml*?

Comment: @Boris "Вопрос задан 4 года 4 месяца назад"